# Maximum size of leaseable space on Solana

Tags: anchor, solana-program

what is the maximum size of a program that can be rented on solana. And can I rent more when needed ?

Answer (score 6):

Solana accounts are currently [limited to 10MB of storage](https://docs.solana.com/developing/programming-model/accounts#creating). Generally, a compiled program binary should not come anywhere near this limit. For example, the [Openbook's executable binary is just under 469Kb. If an account your program uses is running out of space, you can [use the `realloc` command](https://dev.to/jacobcreech/how-to-change-account-size-on-solana-55b4) to give it a larger memory allocation.

See also https://docs.solana.com/cli/usage#solana-rent

Comment: A couple more links for those curious about the source code -- here's where it's defined:
https://docs.rs/solana-program/latest/solana_program/system_instruction/constant.MAX_PERMITTED_DATA_LENGTH.html and here's where it's imported/enforced at runtime: https://docs.rs/solana-runtime/latest/src/solana_runtime/system_instruction_processor.rs.html#99